# Vagrant Up , issue with git key?

Tags: vagrant

hope someone can help me. I recently purchased Rapid Application Development
with CakePHP 2.0 by Jose Diaz-Gonzalez and I have been struggling to set up vagrant.

I am using the latest version of virtual-box, vagrant and chef and I am following the instructions to the letter, however I am receiving the following error:

```
==> default: [2015-03-12T07:46:39+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2015-03-12T07:46:39+00:00] ERROR: execute[request git key] (/tmp/vagrant-chef/bd885c961fe7ceaf386b7954711e7941/cookbooks/apt/providers/repository.rb line 2) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '2'
==> default: ---- Begin output of gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E1DF1F24 ----
==> default: STDOUT: 
==> default: STDERR: gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created
==> default: gpg: requesting key E1DF1F24 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
==> default: gpg: keyserver timed out
==> default: gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
==> default: ---- End output of gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E1DF1F24 ----
==> default: Ran gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E1DF1F24 returned 2
==> default: [2015-03-12T07:46:39+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

My Stack trace shows the following:

```
Generated at 2015-03-12 08:06:25 +0000
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: execute[request git key] (/tmp/vagrant-chef/bd885c961fe7ceaf386b7954711e7941/cookbooks/apt/providers/repository.rb line 2) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '2'
---- Begin output of gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E1DF1F24 ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key E1DF1F24 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
---- End output of gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E1DF1F24 ----
Ran gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E1DF1F24 returned 2
```

I have googled the error but I am brand new to vagrant and chef and just trying to gain proficiency in cakephp, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the port was blocked after telnetting into the sever "keyserver.ubuntu.com" using the pgp port 11371 and 80 respectively.